# PHP ошибка в синтаксисе

Tags: php

есть вот такой код:

```
<?php 
    require "db.php";  
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $login = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
    $settings = R::findOne('users', 'WHERE `login`=?', [$login]);

    if ($_POST['type'] == 'simple'){
        $settings->$_POST['parameter'] = $_POST['value'];
        R::store($settings);
    }
    $ArrayParametr = [
        'sound',
        $settings->sound
    ];
    $ArrayParametr = [
        'theme',
        $settings->theme
    ];
    $ArrayParametr = [
        'block',
        $settings->block
    ];
    $ArrayParametr = [
        'language',
        $settings->language
    ];
    $ArrayParametr = [
        'vibro',
        $settings->vibro
    ];
    echo( json($ArrayParametr) );

?>
```

Как видите в 8 строке, я не буквально задаю параметр, а беру его из POST запроса. Подозреваю что ошибка там (500 ошибка), валидатор выдает что всё в порядке. Тем не менее скрипт не работает. Что может быть не так? А вернее как правильно написать 8 строку?

Comment: валидатор выдает что всё в порядке --- Какой валидатор??

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Ругается наверное на вот это `$settings->$_POST['parameter']`

Comment: "как правильно написать 8 строку" --- `$settings->{$_POST['parameter']}` ??

Comment: Насчёт 8 строки спасибо, но пока что всё равно ошибку выдает

Comment: Сейчас всё проверю

Comment: Да 8 строка верная, тороплюсь, даже точку с запятой в конце не поставил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всём, особенно Алексею Шиманскому. Вот итоговый рабочий код:

```js
<?php 
    require "db.php";  
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $login = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
    $settings = R::findOne('users', 'WHERE `login`=?', [$login]);

    if ($_POST['type'] == 'simple'){
        $settings->{$_POST['parameter']} = $_POST['value'];
        R::store($settings);
    }
    $ArrayParameter[] = [
        'sound',
        $settings->sound
    ];
    $ArrayParameter[] = [
        'theme',
        $settings->theme
    ];
    $ArrayParameter[] = [
        'block',
        $settings->block
    ];
    $ArrayParameter[] = [
        'language',
        $settings->language
    ];
    $ArrayParameter[] = [
        'vibro',
        $settings->vibro
    ];

    echo( json_encode($ArrayParameter));
?>
```

Ошибка была в 8 строке, после названия массива не поставил квадратные скобки, поскольку массив двумерный и плюс вместо json, надо использовать json_encode.